# 2 anchor texts targetting the same url

Tags: url, seo

I have a query. Suppose here are 2 anchor texts targeting the same URL from within the same domain which one would google consider to be relevant anchor to that URL for SEO purpose ? For Eg: From home page
Anchor text "bid and win" corresponds to http://example.com/123url.php
Anchor text "online auction" corresponds to the same uRL ie http://example.com/123url.php

Basically the 1st anchor text is mentioned in the top of the page & the second anchor text is mentioned in the bottom of the page.

So how would google associate what anchor text should correspond to which URL ? 
Secondly would having 2 or more totally different anchor text pointing to the same URL affect SEO ?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually navigational Links at the Footer of a page can be considered less valuable of links placed in prominence position.
Replaying to you question:

- Google Could consider both URLs depending of their position in the page, footer, header of a web page.
- I do not think so, specially on the same domain, of course give a relevant anchor text to the link is beneficial, so make sure link are useful for you users, and pay attention to the content of the page so to gain better ranking.

Please let me know if this post answer your question.